# Would this be a good place to use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method? (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React by trying to make a simple game. In this game, I have a container component that manages a countdown timer. When the player starts the game I run the following function:

```
startTimer = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            timeLeft:prevState.timeLeft-1
        }))
    },1000)
};
```

My container component has the following render method:

```
render() {


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <GameStats
                gameStarted={this.state.gameStarted}
                question={this.state.question}
                numOfQuestions={this.state.numOfQuestions}
                correctAnswers={this.state.correctAnswers}
                timeLeft={this.state.timeLeft}
            />
            <Board
                gameStarted={this.state.gameStarted}
                startGame={this.startGame}
                squareClicked={this.squareClickedHandler}
                sqOne={this.state.squareOne}
                sqTwo={this.state.squareTwo}
                sqThree={this.state.squareThree}
                sqFour={this.state.squareFour}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The GameStats component is responsible for rendering the time left whereas the Board component does not use it. Would it therefore make sense to turn the Board component into a class based component and implement the shouldComponentUpdate hook so it doesn't rerender every second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in general you should try to avoid updating the `Board` component every time the clock ticks. It would probably be best to turn your `Board` component to a `PureComponent`.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) `PureComponent` already implements `shouldComponentUpdate`:

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.

Make sure you read the caveat of the shallow comparison further down in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it.